# Best place to show a confirmation modal in a purchase flow

Tags: e-commerce, confirmation, modal

So, I'm working on an insurance ecommerce and would like to get input on where to show a confirmation modal. Let's say I am in the summary page, and there's a "Change Plan" button to choose another plan. I have to options where to show the confirmation modal

Option 1. Once the user clicks the "Change button", s/he is redirected to the Plans Page. And right after the user clicks the "I want this plan" button to commit the change, show the modal.

Option 2. Show the modal in the Summary Page right after the user clicks the "Change Plan" button. And then redirect the user to the Plan Page.

I feel option 1 works better as the modal is shown right before committing the change, but option 2 can work as well. Any feedback is appreciated.

Prototype that shows both options
https://www.figma.com/proto/nuRTOn8ZdMjGLkHrQXOZge/Untitled?node-id=6%3A38&viewport=-570%2C195%2C0.6362286806106567&scaling=min-zoom

Answer (score 1):

The first one feels more natural. The typical flow is:

1. Define a Goal
2. Make a decision
3. Confirm.

In your first flow the user defines their goal: "Change my plan." Their next expectation will likely be "What are my options?" and once they've indicated their intent to pick a different plan, the confirmation reassures them their goal has been reached and ensures the feedback loop is complete. Go with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

User has every right to check the plans anytime so, I don't think Option 2 is feasible. Once the user selects any plan, then only the confirmation modal should show up.